# MyISAM table row size is bigger than the sum of all the columns size?

Tags: myisam

I have a table:

```
CREATE TABLE `playlist` (
  `pid` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `mid` bigint(21) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `status` tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
  `add_time` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `modify_time` int(11) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `filename` char(255) NOT NULL,
  `source` tinyint(3) unsigned NOT NULL
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

From show table status, I got the "Avg_row_length: 788". But the sum of the all the columns is 277 bytes.So I am confused that why the real row size is much larger then the sum of all columns'size?

I hexdump the data file and find the tail of the row is padded by space char:

```
00000000  fd 63 00 00 00 f2 3c 08  00 00 00 00 00 01 33 f4  |.c....<.......3.|
00000010  c7 4b 33 64 c8 4b 31 32  36 39 35 37 35 37 34 37  |.K3d.K1269575747|
00000020  38 31 37 2e 6d 70 33 20  20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20  |817.mp3         |
00000030  20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20  20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20  |                |
*
00000310  20 20 20 01                                       |   .|
00000314
```

MySQL add many spaces into the tail of the row, I don't know why there are so many additional space characters.

Answer (score 1):

That's because you're using a `CHAR` column type; this is a fixed-width column; regardless of how much data you put in there, it'll always take up exactly that number of characters in the data store.  It is designed for columns where you'll *always* have exactly that number of characters, because it's more efficient in that specific case.

What you want in your case is `VARCHAR`; it'll make a note in the column data of how many characters you're storing, and only take up that amount of space in the data store.

Comment: even taking into account the fact that the filename column will always take 255 characters you don't get a sum of 788. The correct answer is that when using the UTF8 character set each char takes **3** bytes, not 1. Taking that into account the row length will in fact be 788. Reference http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/storage-requirements.html